# Sharepoint Server Configuration Database

Tags: sharepoint

I'm a sharepoint newbie and I'm on the installation phase.
My question is:
Can 2 sharepoint servers (different versions & running on separate machines) point to the same configuration database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you cant. As the SharePoint 2010 and 2013 is different. Or you may ask this issue on forums msdn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Several SharePoint servers within the same *farm* (which is an logical concept in SharePoint) do need to point to the same configuration database. However, in your case where you have 2 different versions (I assume you're talking SharePoint 2010 and 2013), that will not work as there are differences in the configuration databases between the two versions.

It is totally okay though to host multiple configuration databases on the same SQL server if you want.

Comment: Do i have to create a new server farm then for my 2nd sharepoint server?

Comment: No you don't. You join an existing farm

Comment: Hi @Alexey. Im not sure if I understand it right but as per Erwin van Hunen 's reply, 2 sharepoint servers in the same farm needs to point to the same configuration database. In my case it won't work as I have 2 diff versions. Can I join an existing farm and specify a new configuration database?

Comment: oh, sorry, i missed that part. Then yes, you have to use another config database, and subsequently, it's going to be a different farm. you may choose an existing farm of appropriate version if available or create a new one.